# Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, bundle, osx-mavericks

I wasting a day by struggling against that damn error. Hope you'll help me. It happens when I try to launch `bundle exec cucumber -r features`

*Stacktrace:*

```
Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `spec'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/Users/volodymyr/projects/conductor/conductor/cucumber/features/support/databases.rb:27:in `<class:ReportingDb>'
/Users/volodymyr/projects/conductor/conductor/cucumber/features/support/databases.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/volodymyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

*Gemfile:*

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'watir-webdriver'
gem 'parallel_tests'
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'i18n'
gem 'json'
gem 'logger'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'mysql2', '> 0.3'
gem 'factory_girl'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'rubyzip' # Required for rubyXL
gem 'rubyXL'
gem 'syntax'
gem 'rake'
gem 'mail'

group :development do
  gem 'guard-cucumber' # Guard for Cucumber
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard' # OSX notifications! :)
end
```

Comment: please show `Gemfile` and `database.yml`

Comment: please post just `Gemfile` and your `config/database.yml` (anonymised!)

Comment: @Зелёный posted Gemfile, can't find database.yml

Comment: @spickermann posted Gemfile, can't find database.yml

Answer (score 1):

You must define the database connection and provide the credentials in a `database.yml` file in your `config` folder. If you do not have this file, create it and add our settings to it:

```
# in config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: DATABASE_NAME_FOR_DEVELOPMENT
  username: DATABASE_USER
  password: DATABASE_PASSWORD
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: DATABASE_NAME_FOR_TESTS
  username: DATABASE_USER
  password: DATABASE_PASSWORD
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the installation, verify your OS and install again. For example, I have Xubuntu 16.04, so i followed this steps.

```
wget -qO - https://deb.packager.io/key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://deb.packager.io/gh/opf/openproject-ce xenial stable/6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openproject.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openproject
```

This is the [installation guide](https://www.openproject.org/open-source/download/packaged-installation-guide/) for all the systems.